# VBA Copy and Paste Excel Table into Word Document

Tags: vba, excel

The code I'm writing is taking the used range (excluding the first two rows) of a worksheet and copying that table (or tables) onto its own page in a word document. The code was working fine until I had to make some changes to it... Right now the problem is that it is looping through all the worksheets in the workbook, but re-pasting the contents of the last worksheet only. Also, I can't seem to get VBA to recognize the pasted tables as tables -- so it isn't letting me center them in the word document. Any ideas for how I can solve these problems? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub toWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fromWB As Variant
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim docName As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
wdDoc.Activate
'Creates InputBox that allows user to enter name to save document as
docName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Document Name", Title:="Save Word Document", Type:=2)
wdDoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=docName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument 'Saves document under user-provided name

fromWB = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbook(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", Title:="Open Merged Data")
If fromWB <> False Then
Set fromWB = Workbooks.Open(fromWB)
Set fromWB = ActiveWorkbook
ElseIf fromWB = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
    GoTo ResetSettings
End If


For Each ws In fromWB.Worksheets
    Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).Resize(Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).Paste
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Characters.Count - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
Next ws
   wdDoc.Styles("Normal").NoSpaceBetweenParagraphsOfSameStyle = True
wdDoc.Save
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Imported into Word Document"


ResetSettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you place a break point at `Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")` and advance line by line. As you already set this variable to the Word.Application setting it in your loop might be restarting the object, eliminating your previously pasted text. You can also try commenting that line and see if just making `wdApp.Visible = True` will work. Regards.

Comment: I commented out that line and it didn't affect the code.

Answer (score 2):

The issues I see with your code are:-

1. `Set fromWB = ActiveWorkbook` is superfluous and can be removed
2. You are referencing `Range` without a worksheet prefix, so it will always default to the current active worksheet (which is the one that would be visible when you open the workbook).  Normally I would say to do this: `ws.Range("A2")` but in this case, I would suggest `ws.Activate` as the first statement inside your `For Each` loop since you are using physical actions such as copy/paste.
3. To be a good resource citizen, you should be quitting Excel and setting `fromWB = Nothing` to release the memory.  In fact, in VBA, you should be setting all assigned object variables to `Nothing` before you leave the method.

Comment: Great! Those helped. Thank you. However, for some worksheets there is nothing in row 3 or below, so the code stops running when it reaches one of these worksheets. Do you know of a way I can get around this?

Comment: I am assuming row 2 has column headings, then you can simply put `If ws.Range("A3").Value <> "" Then` to test for content inside your `For Each` loop and it will skip the whole worksheet if it's empty.

Comment: Thank you! One last question... I'm trying to center align the tables after I paste them with `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
       Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter` but I don't think it's recognizing the table. Do you know how I can change this for it to work? @joehanna

Comment: If you format the data in Excel as a table (Ribbon: "Home => "Format as Table") and you copy/paste the whole table, then it should be recognised in Word as a table and keep its formatting/style too.

Comment: It seems to keep all the formatting, except that it gets rid of the space before each data entry in each cell. When I manually copy the table into the word document, there is a space before each number, but when I run the code, there isn't. do you know why?